# Artifact directory for rendering template in custom Grails 3 script

Tags: grails-3.0

In the Grails 3.2.3 documentation, it shows this piece of code as an example of a custom script:

```
def scriptName = args[0]
def model = model(scriptName)
def overwrite = flag('force') ? true : false

render  template: template('artifacts/Script.groovy'),
    destination: file("src/main/scripts/${model.lowerCaseName}.groovy"),
    model: model,
    overwrite: overwrite
```

Where is the artifacts directory in the grails-app or src hierarchies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example you cite, the `artifacts` directory is in the profile's jar file.

(the relevant source is:  https://github.com/grails-profiles/base/tree/master/templates)

In general any profile or plugin that has a templates directory, it will be found in the jar for the profile or the plugin.

But your project can override anything from a profile or a plugin.  You follow the same pattern for the different kinds of templates rooted in your project at `src/main/templates`.

For example, if you say

```
grails install-templates
```

A directory `src/main/templates/scaffolding` will be created containing copies of the templates applied by the scaffolding plugin that you can edit to customize how scaffolding views, generated controllers and so on, render.

For script templates, the path is `artifacts` not `scaffolding`, so if you have a script template or a domain class template you like better than the default one, you would put it in

```
src/main/templates/artifacts
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This is exactly what I needed.